# How do I delete texts from the OS itself?

Tags: sms

I use [Textra](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.textra) for texting. I recently went through and deleted all my texts from Textra to try and clean up my phone. But if I look at contacts, I can still see some recent texts listed.

I know Textra and other third party text apps don't store the texts, the OS does. How do I clean up old texts from the OS itself?

Comment: The OS only stores what the apps instruct the OS to store. BTW. From your question it is not clear how a contact can contain recent texts. Does "Textra" store texts in contacts?

Comment: When I migrated away from whatever the default android texting app is over to Textra, I could see messages in both apps. And I would imagine if I downloaded another 3rd party texting app, that would be able to read texts from the OS also. There is no standard procedure for cleaning old texts from a phone?

Comment: Something to clarify: did you set Textra as the default messaging app when deleting the texts? Note that only the default messaging app has write access to delete the messages on the OS level ([SMS content provider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms)). Also, from where/which app did you see the contacts that have recent texts listed? Otherwise, have you checked with other messaging apps that the texts are still there? Perhaps the app that shows the contacts stores a copy of recent texts instead.