# Where are text messages stored on Android 13 (Pixel 6)?

Tags: sms, android-13, google-pixel-6

All the research I've done told me it's located at Internal Memory > data > user_de > 0 > com.android > providers.telephony > databases > mmssms.db

Best I could find was Internal Storage > Android > data > com.android.providers.telephony > Files

Which is empty. But my Textra app has to be restoring these files from somewhere because when I got this phone the messaged were successfully restored from my old phone.

I ask because on convo was deleted, also when I switched to the default messaging app I could briefly see the old messages in that convo, then they disappeared, why?

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you have Google Cloud backup activated this could be the source where the SMS were stored. The file `mmssms.db` is only accessible on rooted devices as users can not access app private internal storage.

Comment: @Robert Okay thank you, are you saying that the Messenger app doesn't access `mmssms.db` because it can't? And therefore looks in Google Cloud backup? Or are you saying that `mmssms.db` is only restricted to users?

Comment: Perhaps related: [How do I delete texts from the OS itself? (Using Textra)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/253542/44325). I'm not sure how the Textra app works, but `mmssms.db` is part of the SMS content provider that can be manipulated using content provider API, but the file cannot be accessed directly either by the apps or the user. "*because when I got this phone the messaged were successfully restored from my old phone*" this looks like the case of [Google Cloud backup and restore](https://support.google.com/android/answer/2819582).

Comment: Possible canonical duplicate: [Where on the file system are SMS messages stored?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/16915/44325)

Comment: @AndrewT. Hey sorry I know this is a late reply, does this mean I can use the API to access the texts?